# Python script to get the date value

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am trying to execute the below python script to get the number of files in the remote server.

The problem here is the last folder is created based on the date. The grep command which is created for fetching the date value is not converting into date in the remote server.The commented find code  will work well but i am looking to pass the date as argument. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/b2s/bin/python

import paramiko
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()- datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
date= now.strftime("%Y%m%d")

print "date is" +date

client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('host', username='username')

# grepCommand='find /usr/local/folder1/folder2/folder3/20170712_060013 -type f  |wc -l'
grepCommand='find /usr/local/folder1/folder2/folder3/${date}_* -type f  |wc -l'

stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command(grepCommand)
data=stdout.readlines()
for i in data:
        print(i.encode('ascii','replace'))

# print data

client.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `date` contains the date as you want it to appear, just insert that value into your `grepCommand` string like this:

```
grepCommand = 'find /usr/local/folder1/folder2/folder3/{}_* -type f  |wc -l'.format(date)
```